# How to pass a object with list key and value in Rest Api with Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I pass an object with the format data to Spring Boot Api:

```
const examRequest = {
  examId: 10,
  timer: 100,
  anwsers: "{1:2, 2:1}", (pair question ID and value)
};

const submitData = (examRequest) => {
  const url = "/exams/submit";
  return axios.post(url, examRequest);
```

},

Back-end:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/exams/submit")
public ResponseEntity<?> submitData(
        @Valid @RequestBody AnswerResponse answerResponse) {
    return examService.submitData(answerResponse);
}
```

AnswerResponse.java

```
private Long examId;

private Integer timer;

List<AnswerPair> answers;
```

AnswerPair.java

```
private Long questionId;

private Long keyAnswer;
```

But I cannot pass the data to the backend and get the error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<AnswerPair>` out of START_OBJECT token

Please help me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In the backend you are expecting answers as array of objects, but in frontend you are sending string.

Request object need to be like below

```
const examRequest = {
  examId: 10,
  timer: 100,
  anwsers: [
    {questionId: 1, keyAnswer: 2}, 
    {questionId: 2, keyAnswer: 1}
  ]
};
```

Comment: yes, thank you so much and more question:

please help me convert {1:2, 2:1} to 
[
 {questionId: 1, keyAnswer: 2}, 
 {questionId: 2, keyAnswer: 1}
]

Comment: Sure are you creating new question or where should i post the answer?

Comment: I have just resolved the problem. Thank you so much :D